# Teradata: How to view data distribution within the column in a table?

Tags: sql, statistics, histogram, teradata

I would like to get some kind of histogram of data distribution in column in order to understand statistic problems.

The first step is to get total information:

```
help stats tbName;
```

For sure it is not enough, I will just get number of unique values. So how can I further investigate data distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SHOW STATS VALUES COLUMN myCol ON myTable;
```

returns all details about histograms and biased values.

For multi-column stats:

```
SHOW STATS VALUES COLUMN (myCol1, myCol2) ON myTable;
```

For all stats defined on a table:

```
SHOW STATS VALUES ON myTable;
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same for multiple columns? I mean there can be separate statistics for 2 columns, for example

Comment: @Rocketq: Edited my answer